# how to find maximum value of $|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a real valued analytic function with $f(0)=1$ so the set $\{z:f(z)\ne 1\}$ is empty as $f$ will be constant right?

could anyone tell me how to find maximum value of $|z|$? given that $|z+{1\over z}|=a$

$|z+{1\over z}|\le |z|+{1\over |z|}\ge a\Rightarrow |z|^2-a|z|+1\ge 0$ then?

$|z|={a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}\over 2}$ are roots

Comment: Are these two questions? Or is the first statement somehow related to the second part?

Comment: two seperate question.

Comment: It is preferable to ask different questions separately, or *at very least* make it clear that they are in fact two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f:U\subset \mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic non-constant is an open mapping.

Note that $\displaystyle f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}$ mapped circumferences into ellipses
$$f(\{z:|z|=r\})=\{z:|z-2|+|z+2|=2(r+\frac{1}{r})\}$$
$|z|=r$ is maximum when the circumference $|z|=a$ is tangent (minor axis) to an ellipse therefore $$r-\frac{1}{r}=a$$

Comment: do not understand .......................

Comment: Joukowski mapping  http://books.google.com.pe/books?id=1DItN16-t-MC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=complex+Joukowski&source=bl&ots=bLIuSOOnSO&sig=wa2EARst6cciq1T9K1GlbEwbhfI&hl=es&sa=X&ei=3VltUpCzI4a_kQei1IFo&ved=0CHMQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=complex%20Joukowski&f=false